# rails: get items with associated with multiple given tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

noob question here. I have a has_many :through relationship between items and tags. Finding all items associated with a given tag is simple enough:

```
things=Tag.find(1).items
```

But what if I want to find all items associated with more than one given tag? I was thinking something like:

```
things=Tag.find(1).items
Tag.find(2).things # wrong, but you get the idea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array union operator.

```
things = Tag.find(1).items | Tag.find(2).items
```

That will create an object for *every* item for *both* tags, which could be way too much depending on what you're trying to do. If you want something a little more scalable, you can do the lookup on the join table.

```
things = ItemTags.find_by_sql("
  SELECT item_id, COUNT(tag_id) AS tag_count 
  FROM item_tags
  WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2)
  GROUP_BY item_id
  HAVING tag_count = 2;
").map(&:item)
```

Just wrote that in browser, so it could be completely wrong. Also, there is probably a way to do that with activerecord finders that would be nicer that a find_by_sql.

Comment: Oh my bad. Use '&' instead. It's the intersection operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
things = Things.where(:tag => [1, 2])
things = Things.where('tag in :tags', [1, 2])
```

etc...